# GhostScript Font issue when i am converting pdf to image in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ghostscript

I am using GhostScript (64 bit) **gswin64.exe** Please suggest how to resolve this.if my pdf font is **vani** format and after converted in image it has **Arial** format. But i need it actual font format that was in pdf.

Here my code -

```
public static void PdfToJpg(string inputPDFFile, string outputImagesPath)
            {
               string ghostScriptPath = @"C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.19\bin\gswin64.exe";
                String ars = "-dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pngalpha -r300 -dBATCH -dSAFER -sOutputFile=" + outputImagesPath +Guid.NewGuid() +".png -sPAPERSIZE=a4 " + inputPDFFile;

                Process proc = new Process();

                proc.StartInfo.FileName = ghostScriptPath;
                proc.StartInfo.Arguments = ars;
                proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        enter code here
                proc.Start();
                proc.WaitForExit();
            }

    calling-from 





public ActionResult Index()
                {
                    PdfToJpg("C:/Users/admin/Desktop/testdoc.pdf", "E:/output/");
                    return View();
                }
```

If any one have resolved this issue so please let me know.

Comment: You forgot to describe an actual issue.

Comment: Actually, in my pdf file Vani  font used and when my image is generate then that is Arial fomat.

Comment: You can [edit] your question to add any details you forgot about.

Comment: I have edited.....

Comment: Almost certainly your PDF file calls for a font called Vani, but does not include it. Of course, without seeing your PDF file its rather hard to tell....If you have the font available you can add it to Ghostscript's list of fonts and then it will use it. If you don't have the font available, and its not in the PDF file, then how is Ghostscript supposed to use it ?